# Can't get JSON to work with Dimple.js instead of a TSV file

Tags: json, dimple.js

Problem:  I can't get Dimple.js to work with a JSON Array of data instead of the tsv file.  I want to eventually fill the JSON array from PHP/MySQL, but can't get it to work manually.

I have the code below, but when I switch out the .tsv for my new data variable it gives me all kind of errors.  I feel like it is a simple fix, but have tried it various ways and none of them work.

I commented out the manual data I tried to add that was giving me an error.  What I have here is working, but I can't figure out how to switch to the JSON array.....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                /**var data = [
                                {Month:"May-2012",Unit Sales:"50",Channel:"First One"},
                                {Month:"May-2012",Unit Sales:"50",Channel:"First One"},
                                {Month:"April-2012",Unit Sales:"50",Channel:"First One"},
                                {Month:"June-2012",Unit Sales:"50",Channel:"First One"},
                                {Month:"July-2012",Unit Sales:"50",Channel:"First One"},
                                {Month:"August-2012",Unit Sales:"50",Channel:"First One"},
                                {Month:"Sept-2012",Unit Sales:"50",Channel:"First One"},
                                {Month:"Oct-2012",Unit Sales:"50",Channel:"First One"}
                            ];
            **/

                var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 590, 400);
                d3.tsv("PMSI-AlignAlytics-dimple-2e3a06a/data/example_data.tsv", function (data) {
                //d3.tsv(data, function (data) {
                  var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
                  myChart.setBounds(60, 30, 510, 305)
                  var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Month");
                  x.addOrderRule("Date");
                  myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Unit Sales");
                  myChart.addSeries("Channel", dimple.plot.bar);
                  myChart.addLegend(60, 10, 510, 20, "right");
                  myChart.draw();
                });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to my question.  Instead of trying to wrap the details in a function like it was here:

```
d3.tsv("PMSI-AlignAlytics-dimple-2e3a06a/data/example_data.tsv", function (data) { 
   //
});
```

I can remove this and the trailing and it works fine.